Why my javascript function detected as not function on callback?
recently I try to jump into coding again after stopping for almost 7 years long.
What I'm troubled now is a simple case where function became "not" function on callback.
Here is where it happens:
function xhrcall() {
   let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.responseType = "json";
   xhr.open("POST", "/api", true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xhr.send("token=xxxxxxx");
   xhr.onload = () => {
      let x = xhr.status == 200 ? xhr.response : false;     //console.log(x) gives proper response
      return x;
   }
}

When I try to declare it in variable or use it as callback it gives me Uncaught Error.
For example if I declare it like this
let fn = xhrcall()
console.log(fn)        //will gives me undefined result

window.callback = xhrcall()
callback()             //will gives uncaught error not a function

As I recalled, this should be fine and working yet it not.
This could be duplicate questions but I hope someone could explain what is actually wrong here. Did I miss the function scope? or is it the problem with return x?
Thank you.

let fn = xhrcall() means "call the function named xhrcall and whatever it returns, assign it to the variable fn".

When you want to pass or assign a function for something else to use it, you have to leave off the (). So, let fn = xhrcall;

This question is similar to: Why is my function call that should be scheduled by setTimeout executed immediately?.

@Pointy, as you said, let fn = xhrcall() should assign whatever value it returns to the variable fn yet what I got using console.log(fn) is undefined value instead, so something must be missing here.

Your xhrcall() function does not return anything. The "onload" callback returns something, but that has nothing to do with what xhrcall() returns. A return statement only works for the function that is its direct containing function.

@Pointy Ah.. now that you point that, I just realized that the return x is outside from xhrcall() scope, no wonder it's undefined. Now I know what to do. Thank you.

By default, if a function's execution doesn't end at a return statement, or if the return keyword doesn't have an expression after it, then the return value is undefined.
xhrcall() returns undefined [1]
This value is assigned to fn and neither the global property undefined nor the primitive value undefined are invocable hence your observations are consistent.

If you need the value that the arrow function assigned to xhr.onload will return, you have to find a different way to collect that value since the arrow function will not be invoked synchronously.
You can collect that value using an EventTarget that an Event will be dispatched to when the arrow function assigned to xhr.onload is fired and completes. Event listeners listening to this EventTarget will be invoked when this Event is dispatched.
For example:
const xhrApiTarget = new EventTarget()
xhr.onload = () => {
    let x = xhr.status == 200 ? xhr.response : false
    const apiResEvt = new Event("api-res")
    apiResEvt.response = x
    xhrApiTarget.dispatchEvent(apiResEvt)
}
xhrApiTarget.addEventListener("api-res", (apiResEvt) => { apiResEvt.response })

[1] Don’t confuse with the return in the arrow function assigned to xhr.onload.

Thank your for providing your answer. Never cross my mind to trigger an event and return the value through an event response. While I've already fix my code using callback param, I'll pick your answer here and experiment it later. This is interesting and prick me up. Thank you.
